# Readlink not working over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, symbolic-link

I'm trying to send a bash command over SSH using `ssh -q $REMOTE -x "command"`.
Because I have multiple bash commands, I'm using `<< EOF`.

The problem is that the readlink command returns me an empty string when I assign its result to a variable. When I call it directly, it's not.

Here is a simplified version of my code :

```sh
ssh -q $REMOTE -x << EOF
    LINK="/path/to/my/link" # the link points to /path/to/my/file
    readlink $LINK # outputs /path/to/my/file
    TEST=$(readlink -f "$LINK")
    echo $TEST # outputs an empty string
EOF
```

At that point I put the same code in a shell script on the remote machine and tried to call the shell script :

```sh
# local machine
ssh -q $REMOTE -x << EOF
    ./test-script
EOF
```

```sh
# remote machine "test-script"
LINK="/path/to/my/link" # the link points to /path/to/my/file
readlink $LINK # outputs /path/to/my/file
TEST=$(readlink -f "$LINK")
echo $TEST # outputs /path/to/my/file
```

Suddently it's working, when I'm calling the remote script everything works fine, but why is it not working over ssh ?

Comment: Side note: [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the here document, your variables are being evaluated on the source side.  If you want to have your variables be evaluated on the target side, escape the $.  For example,

```
ssh -q $REMOTE -x << EOF
    LINK="/path/to/my/link"
    readlink \$LINK
    TEST=\$(readlink -f "\$LINK")
    echo \$TEST
EOF
```

Hope this helps

Comment: After a long time searching for the right solution someone finally came up with something very straightforward an not using weird tricks. I'll remember `\$` forever.

Answer (score 0):

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents):

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>         here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> If any part of *word* is quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.

So either escape `$` (like [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1374790/432690) says) or use `<< "EOF"` (with quotes); otherwise syntax like `$variable` and `$(…)` will be resolved locally.